# Setting the Page Cache headers in the mvc.getPageRendering Pipeline

Tags: mvc, pipelines, caching

I need to patch in a fix for a bug with Sitecore MVC Caching (confirmed by support).

The pipeline I need to patch into is:

I need to set cache settings on the page object, e.g:

`page.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);`

However to do that I need access to the System.Web.UI.Page.

Whatever I try the page is coming up null:

```
PageContext page = Context.Page;
Page page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;
Page page = Sc.Context.Page.Page;
```

I know I can use:

```
Page page = PageContext.CurrentOrNull.Item;
```

To get the Sitecore page item but I need the System.Web.UI.Page, not the item.

I'm guessing this is due to the order in which the MVC Pipelines run etc: http://jockstothecore.com/sitecore-mvc-item-maze/

Any help would be appreciated.

**Other info:** Sitecore 8.1 Update 2, MVC

Comment: Makes no sense to me. System.Web.UI.Page is the class you inherit in an .aspx file, e.g. a Webforms layout. It would not come into play in MVC.

Comment: Ahr yes your right Mark, I'm being a bit of an idiot. I've got it working now, just needs to be HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments I was going about this in the wrong way for MVC. This is the solution for my pipeline:

```
public override void Process(GetPageRenderingArgs args)
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object)args, "args");
            Profiler.StartOperation("Update browser caching headers.");
            HttpContext currentContext = HttpContext.Current;
            Item currentItem = PageContext.CurrentOrNull.Item;

            if (currentContext == null)
                return;

            MvcBrowserCaching.SetCacheHeaders(currentContext);

            if (currentItem != null)
                MvcBrowserCaching.SetUpdateHeaders(currentItem, currentContext);

            Profiler.EndOperation();
        }
```

I can then set the cache like so:

```
currentContext.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
```